# Avoid testing duplicate values with ScalaTest forAll

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck, property-based-testing

I'm playing with property-based testing on ScalaTest and I had the following code:

```
val myStrings = Gen.oneOf("hi", "hello")
forAll(myStrings) { s: String =>
  println(s"String tested: $s")
}
```

When I run the `forAll` code, I've noticed that the same value is tried more than once, e.g.

```
String tested: hi
String tested: hello
String tested: hi
String tested: hello
String tested: hi
String tested: hello
...
```

I was wondering if there is a way for, given the code above, for each value in `oneOf` to be tried only once. In other words, to get ScalaTest not to use the same value twice.

Even if I used other generators, such as `Gen.alphaStr`, I'd like to find a way to avoid testing the same String twice. The reason I'm interested in doing this is because each test runs against a server running in a different process, and hence there's a bit of cost involved, so I'd like to avoid testing the same thing twice.

Comment: What is the nature of the variable `primitives`?

Comment: Maybe `forAll(primitives.distinct) {` works?

Comment: @mattinbits, amended the code, it should be `forAll(myStrings)`. @marstran, there's no distinct in `Gen`.

Comment: I think you have to explicitly check for duplicates - I updated my answer with ConcurrentHashMap approach. I do not think there could be native support for that in scalacheck as it would require it to memorize every generated value at the risk of OOM (which you have to deal with as well so I recommend to use size-bounded collection or an additional check rather than applying ConcurrentHashMap approach naively).

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is seems to be against scalacheck ideology(see Note1); however it's kind of possible (with high probability) by reducing the number of samples:

```
scala> forAll(oneOf("a", "b")){i => println(i); true}.check(Test.Parameters.default.withMinSuccessfulTests(2))
a
b
+ OK, passed 2 tests.
```

Note that you can still get aa/bb sometimes, as scala-check is built on randomness and statistical approach. If you need to always check all combinations - you probably don't need scala-check:

```
scala> assert(Set("a", "b").forall(_ => true))
```

Basically `Gen` allows you to create an infinite collection that represents a **distribution** of input values. The more values you generate - the better sampling you get. So if you have N possible states, you can't guarantee that they won't repeat in an infinite collection.

The only way to do exactly what you want is to explicitly check for duplicates before calling the service. You can use something like `Option(ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbscent(value, value)).isEmpty` for that. Keep in mind it is a risk of OOM so be careful to take care of the amount of generated values and maybe even add an explicit check.

Note1) What scalacheck is needed for reducing number of combinations from maximum (which is more than 100) to some value that still gives you a good check. **So scalacheck is useful when a set of possible inputs is really huge. And in that case the probability of repetitions is really small**

P.S.
Talking about `oneOf` (from scaladoc):

> def oneOf[T](t0: T, t1: T, tn: T*): Gen[T]
>
> Picks a random value from a list

See also (examples are a bit outdated): [How can I reduce the number of test cases ScalaCheck generates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365417/how-can-i-reduce-the-number-of-test-cases-scalacheck-generates)

Answer (score -1):

I would aim to increase the entropy of values. Using random sentences will increase it a lot, although not (theoretically) fixing the issue.

```
val genWord = Gen.onOf("hi", "hello")

def sentanceOf(words: Int): Gen[String] = {
   Gen.listOfN(words, genWord).map(_.mkString(" ")
}
```